# How can I tell when my Android alert dialog is cancelled?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

Here is my alert:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity.this)
    .setMessage("You have unsaved text. Are you sure you want to leave?")
    .setCancelable(true)
    .setNegativeButton("Leave", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
        {
            finish();
        }
    })
    .setPositiveButton("Stay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {}
    }).show();
```

Notice how I allow the alert to be cancelable: `.setCancelable(true)`

How can I run some code once the alert is cancelled by the user pressing the back button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [AlertDialog.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html) documentation on [Android's website](http://developer.android.com), you can use the [setOnCancelListener (DialogInterface.OnCancelListener onCancelListener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setOnCancelListener%28android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener%29) method to handle when the dialog is cancelled.

```
.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) 
    {
        // do what you need when the dialog is cancelled
    }
})
```

So, your code would change to this:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity.this)
    .setMessage("You have unsaved text. Are you sure you want to leave?")
    .setCancelable(true)
    .setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) 
        {
            // do what you need when the dialog is cancelled
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Leave", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
        {
            finish();
        }
    })
    .setPositiveButton("Stay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {}
    }).show();
```

Comment: Why ask a question to give an answer 1 minute later? If it was a difficult thing or constructive, I could understand that your motive is to teach, but in this case, ....

Comment: @LazyNinja This is a QnA for myself (I didn't figure it out the next minute). I tried to find this answer and couldn't. I'm sure there's another answer out there, but it I couldn't find it based on the title perhaps. Then I figured it out myself and decided to post it so perhaps someone else in my shoes could find an easy example like this. How is this not constructive? A lot of questions on this site are not difficult, but people need specific answers. This is one of them.